# CSS text-shadow value RegEx

Tags: javascript, css, regex

I have the following RegEx to validate an input for the CSS `text-shadow` property

`/^(-?[0-9]+px\s?){2,3}(#[a-fA-F0-9]{6}|#[a-fA-F0-9]{3}|red|orange|black|white|purple|blue|red|yellow|green|brown|aqua|pink|teal)$/`

Which works pretty fine for simple cases like `2px 2px #ff0000;`

But it doesn't work for multiple values e.g.

`text-shadow : -1px -1px 0 #ffffff, 1px -1px 0 #ffffff, -1px 1px 0 #ffffff, 1px 1px 0 #ffffff;`

How can I "extend" the previous RegEx to support every `text-shadow` case?

Comment: @Tushar yes, javascript

Comment: @Tushar you do them on your own or use software ?

Comment: What about initial and inherit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following RegEx

[`^(-?\d+px\s+-?\d+px(?:\s*\d+)?\s*#(?:\[a-zA-Z0-9\]{3}(?:\[a-zA-Z0-9\]{3})?|red|orange|black|white|purple|blue|red|yellow|green|brown|aqua|pink|teal)\s*\[,;\]\s*)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/lK3yK2/1)

Here's another RegEx using alteration/OR condition. The first part of the RegEx match the simple syntax, the second part match the individual values for each side.

[`^(-?\d+px\s+-?\d+px\s+#(\[a-fA-F0-9\]{3})(\[a-fA-F0-9\]{3})?;?)|(-?\d+px\s+-?\d+px\s+\d+\s+#(\[a-zA-Z0-9\]{3}(\[a-zA-Z0-9\]{3})?),?\s*){4};?`](https://regex101.com/r/lK3yK2/2)

**Explanation:**

1. `-?\d+px\s+-?\d+px\s+`

   - `-?`: Match hyphen `-` optionally
   - `\d+`: Match one or more digits
   - `px`: Match `px` literal
   - `\s+`: Match one or more spaces
2. `#([a-fA-F0-9]{3})([a-fA-F0-9]{3})?`

   - `#`: Match hash `#`
   - `[a-fA-F0-9]{3}`: Match 3-characters hex
   - `([a-fA-F0-9]{3})?`: Match 3-characters hex optionally

---

Another one supporting formats specified in the MDN<sup>[Syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-shadow#Syntax)</sup>

[`^text-shadow:\s*(initial|unset|inherit|(-?\d+(px)?\s*){2,3}(#((\[a-f0-9\]{3}){1,2})|\[a-z-\]+)|(#((\[a-f0-9\]{3}){1,2})|\[a-z-\]+)\s*(-?\d+(px)?\s*){2,3});?$`](https://regex101.com/r/lK3yK2/3)

Comment: You are the regex god :D ?

Comment: I am trying to do the same for the `box-shadow` so I tried to repeat once more the `-?\d+px\s+` part in the regex,  `^(-?\d+px\s+-?\d+px\s+-?\d+px\s+#([a-fA-F0-9]{3})([a-fA-F0-9]{3})?;?)|(-?\d+px\s+-?\d+px\s+\d+\s+#([a-zA-Z0-9]{3}([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})?),?\s*){4};?` it works in the simple case, but not in the case with multiple values. Any idea what I am doing wrong? Thx a lot.